# Apache Mod Re-write - re-write causing 500 Error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using a go daddy virtual server and have uploaded the following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php?|images|styles|scripts|favicon\.ico|favicon\.png|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I am trying to remove index.php? from the URL, but the fails causing 500 errors.

Can anyone suggest why this may cause a 500 error?
Thanks in advance

Comment: webmasters.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `$1` from the `RewriteCond`, since the `RewriteCond` is evaluated before the `RewriteRule`. Maybe that's it, and you should write:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|...)
RewriteRule ...
```